# Why are there 0 values in the 0 index of an array when constructing the value type?

Tags: arrays, swift, repeat

Short question, I need an array that is limited to a dimension of 9, which I am doing with the code I am showing, but due to some changes, I need it to contain another array, that is [Int, Int], and I already It has happened that the first value of the array is [0,0] and I have the doubt of why this happens and how I must solve it.

Here the code:

```
var array = Array(repeating:[[Int(), Int()]], count:9)
array[2].append([2,1])
print(array)

// [[[0, 0]], [[0, 0]], ----->[[0, 0], [2, 1]]<------, [[0, 0]], [[0, 0]], [[0, 0]], [[0, 0]], [[0, 0]], [[0, 0]]]
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but what exactly is not working as expected?

Comment: You're appending, which means: keeping `[0, 0]` and adding to the end of the `[2]` array `[2, 1]`

Answer (score 0):

Because you are adding [2,1] at array[2], which means you are starting you append after three elements, because array is zero-indexed.

Comment: Ok, I solved it with array[2] = [[2,1]], but there is some way to construct the array with [Int, Int] and that can do append and that the first value that I enter is in index 0?

Comment: Syntax to create array you need is this: Array(repeating:[Int(), Int()], count:9)
Additional parenthesis are not required.
After this, remember that append just put your element at the end of the structure, so if you want to set first value you need to set it at array[0]

Comment: mhh, If I create it that way, add a second value to the array only,                var array2 =  Array(repeating:[Int(), Int()], count:9)
array2[2].append(2) -> [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0, 2],..... I need this result: [[[0, 0]], [[0, 0]], ---> [[2, 1], [2, 5]] <---,